# What kind of bubble this？

Tags: cell-biology, cell-culture

[image]
This is the MARC-145 I cultivated. Recently, many bubbles appeared in the cells. I don’t know why.

Answer (score 1):

Late stage [apoptosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apoptosis). Specifically what you are seeing here is cells that have undergone the blebbing stage and are releasing or have released apoptotic bodies.